# Removing Duplicate Rows in Employee Demographic Data Pull

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I am doing a data pull to get some demographic information on employees.
I had an issue with missing employees because not everyone has a phone number (I 
don't know why)

Now I have duplicates because some people have a primary and not-primary phone number. 
They can be listed as mobile, home, work, etc... What I want is if the employee has a primary phone number to list it, but if they don't have as number at all I want it to be listed as "N/A".

Here is my query below. I appreciate any assitance.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        EJC.PersonTaxIdNo AS [SSN]
        ,EJC.EmpNo AS [Employee ID]
        ,ISNULL(EJC.Salutation, 'N/A') AS [Salutation]
        ,LTRIM(EJC.FirstName) AS [First Name]
        ,LTRIM(EJC.LastName) AS [Last Name]
        ,ISNULL(EJC.NameSuffix,'N/A') AS [Suffix]
        ,VPA.PersonAddress1 AS [Address]
        ,ISNULL(VPA.PersonAddress2,'') AS [Address 2]
        ,VPA.PersonAddressCity AS [City]
        ,VPA.PersonAddressStateAbbrev AS [State]
        ,VPA.PersonAddressPostalCode AS [Zip]
        ,CASE WHEN VPH.PersonPhonePrimaryInd = 1 AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN     VPH.PersonPhoneFromEffectDate AND VPH.PersonPhoneToEffectDate) THEN     VPH.PersonPhoneNo
            WHEN VPH.PersonPhoneNo IS NULL THEN 'N/A' END AS     [Primary Phone]
FROM CNKronos.CNKronos.dbo.EmployeeJob_Curr EJC
    LEFT JOIN CNKronos.CNKronos.dbo.vPERSON_ADDRESSES VPA
        ON EJC.PersonIdNo = VPA.PersonIdNo
    LEFT JOIN CNKronos.CNKronos.dbo.vPERSON_PHONES VPH
        ON EJC.PersonIdNo = VPH.PersonIdNo
WHERE VPA.PersonAddressPrimaryInd = 1
    AND GETDATE() BETWEEN VPA.PersonAddressFromEffectDate AND     VPA.PersonAddressToEffectDate
ORDER BY LTRIM(EJC.LastName), LTRIM(EJC.FirstName)
```

.

```
PersonIdNo | PersonPhoneSeqNo | PersonPhoneTypeIdNo | PersonPhoneType | PersonPhonePrimaryInd | PersonPhoneNo | PersonPhoneExt | PersonPhoneFromEffectDate | PersonPhoneToEffectDate | PersonPhoneChangeDate   | PersonPhoneIsSmsSw | WTKPhoneIdNo   | Timestamp
71376      | 8129             | 23                  | Mobile          | 1                     | 123-456-7890  |                | 2013-11-21 00:00:00.000   | 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-04-10 20:58:53.450 | 0                  | 2              | 0x000000000503DB2E
71376      | 8130             | 21                  | Work            | 0                     | 234-567-8901  |                | 2013-11-21 00:00:00.000   | 3000-01-01 0:00:00.000  | 2014-04-10 20:58:53.760 | 0                  |   3              | 0x000000000503DB31
```

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: looks like VPA and VPH have several data for same user depending on dates?

Comment: Yeah I was trying:

    WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate

This didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you post the table schema only the relevant field to know which phone select for one user and some sample data?

Comment: These are the columns in the vPERSON_PHONES Table:  PersonIdNo -- PersonPhoneSeqNo -- PersonPhoneTypeIdNo -- PersonPhoneTypeIdNo -- PersonPhoneType -- PersonPhonePrimaryInd --PersonPhoneNo -- PersonPhoneExt -- PersonPhoneFromEffectDate -- PersonPhoneToEffectDate -- PersonPhoneChangeDate -- PersonPhoneIsSmsSw -- WTKPhoneIdNo -- Timestamp

Comment: Dont put data or schema in comment just update the question, you can do better format there ;)

Comment: Sample Data:
Here is some sample data:
71376 -- 8129 -- 23 -- Mobile -- 1 -- 123-456-7890 --  -- 2013-11-21 00:00:00.000 -- 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 -- 2014-04-10 20:58:53.450 -- 0 -- 2;  7136 -- 8130 -- 21 -- Work -- 0 -- 234-567-8901 -- 2013-11-21 00:00:00.000 -- 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000 -- 2014-04-10 20:58:53.760 -- 0 -- 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is very hard give you a solution without having a schema. 
So I will try to teach you how do it using CTE [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64442/3)

In the fiddle you can select just the code inside the `WITH` to see the partial result.

That query get you the valid phone inside that date range. User1 have data User2 doesnt

```
with current_phone as (
   SELECT u.name, p.*
   FROM 
       users u 
   left join phone p 
       on u.user_id = p.user_id
       and GETDATE() BETWEEN FromDate and ToDate
)
SELECT name, CASE 
                 WHEN phone is null then 'NA'
                 ELSE phone
             END as phone
FROM current_phone
```

The idea is you do small calculation in the CTE and then join the result with the main table. Hope that help you find your solution.

You also can update the sqlFiddle with a better schema for your case and let me know.